# Extend docker container

Tags: java, docker

I am new to Docker and I have a question regarding possibility to extend docker image after pulling it from docker repository. I need specifically docker image with ubuntu 14.04, java and R. I see there are images separately with the three of them. My question is where is the Dockerfile of newly pulled images so I can extend them?

Answer (score 4):

`docker pull` command just pull a pre-built image. There isn't Dockerfile on your local machine. But you can find the original Dockerfile from Docker Hub. If you use `itzg/ubuntu-openjdk-7` image you can access it's online repository.

https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/itzg/ubuntu-openjdk-7/

Dockerfile is available on Dockerfile tab(Only "Automated Build" repositories have Dockefile tab on Docker Hub).

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER itzg
ENV APT_GET_UPDATE 2014-07-19
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre-headless
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

Below is another Dockerfile from [edwindj/docker-r](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/edwindj/docker-r/dockerfile/).

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER Edwin de Jonge
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y r-base
```

There is no method to automatically merge two or more Dockerfiles, but you can combine these two Dockerfile like below.

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get update

# Install java
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre-headless
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

# Install R
RUN apt-get install -y r-base
```

And build it with `docker build` command.

```
$ docker build nacyot/ubuntu-java-r .
```

Try to java and R command on the container which based on nacyot/ubuntu-java-r image.

```
$ docker run -it nacyot/ubuntu-java-r cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"

$ docker run -it nacyot/ubuntu-java-r java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

$ docker run -it nacyot/ubuntu-java-r R --version
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

It works fine.

There is no magic, but you can extend and bulid (almost) any images which have packages you need at first hand by referencing Dockerfiles on Docker Hub.

Answer (score 3):

Dockerfiles are made to build image but you the inverse operation isn't possible.

If you want to extend an existing image you have 2 solution.

- Run your image in a container, do the change and then commit to a new image. https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/
- Write a Dockerfile with the image you want as base. (1st line of Dockerfile should be `FROM myimage`) https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/

Answer (score 0):

The Repository is your namespace, essentially. So you need to pull the image, which you did. The file is located in the container, if you think about it.

1. List all the images--*sudo docker images* --Will show you the location of the file.
2. List item -- run a shell within a docker container. `$ sudo docker run "your filename"`
3. Now we are inside Docker container. We can list all the files using ls command.
4. Create your own directory if needed, but to answer your question you can stop at #3.
5. From here you could add the image to your own registry, and then pull it from there which honestly makes like easier.

> For simplicity you honestly would only need to do numbers 1 and possibly 2 for
>   sure. When I tried it, #2 was also one I did but that lists the files
>   to add to your own registry when you create your own directory.

Check out this "tutorial" if needed: [Docker Repository Tutorial](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-21-docker-the-missing-tutorial)

Also check out the documentation! [Docker Documentation](https://developer.basespace.illumina.com/docs/content/documentation/native-apps/manage-docker-image#Docker_Repository)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.
You can download a docker image, change it and generate (AKA commit) a new image with a new name (and tag).
To change the container you can either do it manually or with Dockerfile.
I not sure that I can give you all steps in a single answer, but if you follow this little guide I believe that you can get the idea in 10 minutes or less: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/#creating-our-own-images

Answer (score 0):

Merging several images is not possible automatic, but often, the Dockerfiles are easy to follow to create your own version with both R and Java (if thats what you want).

Some upstream containers also uses the `ONBUILD` https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#onbuild entry in their dockerfiles to have something run only when their image is included in another via the `FROM` entry.

If you find one java container you are happy with, just create your own image with a dockerfile and `FROM java-something` on top. Then add R. All the `docker run ...` parameters that you use (entrypoints and cmd) will still work even if you include the container via `FROM`.

If you need to hack on the existing container thats also possible. Take a look at something I created to enable oauth on the gitlab container (before they officially did it) @ https://github.com/xeor/dockerfiles/tree/master/gitlab. There I'm expanding the original image and adding my own set of config tweeks..